# VB.Net Each Browser Behaves Differently Compiled on Other Machine

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

Bear with me here because this might not be as standard as you might think. Or maybe it will be. I can only hope.

I've created a tool which uses two web browsers to read and compare data. It works just fine compiled on my own computer.

Once compiled I've been running it on different VPC's and VPS's and the first loads the data and reads it no problem. That's fine (no problems there).

The second browser loads. All the data is there. But I have it dumping the info into a list box as well as an array (same as the first browser and it works fine for both when I'm running it locally).

Both browsers work the same way using:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.BROWSERNAME.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
```

To find the stats it wants.

I can't work out why one browser would work and not the other. It works every-time locally but as soon as I compile it and put it elsewhere the second won't read.

The only difference between the two I can see is one uses a bit of regex:

```
readdata = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(readdata, "[^\d]", " ")
```

And a stringsplit to break down each line.

```
Dim parts As String() = readdata.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                         StringSplitOptions.None)
```

So my only assumption has to be this is using something which doesn't work on the other systems.

Other systems all have latest .net installed. I have fiddled with regex to change the browser emulation settings (so vb.net browsers can load but I've done the exact same locally and it's worked).

My imports:

```
Imports System.IO 
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Threading
```

But I'm assuming these would all be included with the build or .net framework. Maybe that's where I'm going wrong but I don't know how else to include them.

I'm building for "any cpu". I've tried just copying the .exe over to the other systems and I've tried using the publish part to install it on the other system with the same result.

Any advice would be really appreciated it's driving me nuts here.

Edit:

After some further testing some of the information is reading just fine from the second browser (the same as it would locally). But the second part uses the stringsplit and regex code above so I'm pretty certain it's something about that not going over.

Comment: Have you made sure that IE is updated on the second PC? I believe the .NET browser control utilizes IE, so perhaps the site isn't loading properly enough to parse it due to outdated versions of the browser (assuming that you're using the default control).

Comment: Checked IE is updated. The site is loading properly I can see it just fine on the browser control it's some part of the subroutine reading it which isn't working. Thanks though.

Comment: Is it a possibility to put Visual Studio on the second version so you can run the project with a break point in it to determine where it's breaking down?

Comment: Possibly. I'll have to figure out how to get the browser emulation running on the debug version so it'll load properly. I think I do that with the vhost process I'll have a look.

Comment: It's reading information from the second browser though. Part of it at least. I'm pretty certain it's something about the regex or stringsplit not working on the other system.

Comment: Perhaps it's nothing to do with that; what sort of platform is the second machine? It could be that `Environment.NewLine` is returning something like `\r\n` on the second machine while returning just `\n` on the first. Maybe try hardcoding the sort of newline you're looking for to see if it helps.

Comment: Both Windows 7 64 bit. Slightly different versions of Windows though I'm fairly sure. That sounds plausible though I don't know why it would do that. I can't hard code the newline since it needs to be able to read it from the browser but I can try and run a debug on both to see if the output varies.